# Avoid calling tm_shape() multiple times?

Tags: r

Posting here (rather than Github) as it is not an issue with the `tmap` package.

Situation:

I am doing simple choropleth maps of `varinterest` for U.S. counties (N~3000) using `tmap` (data stored in `data` object). Each map also has a key column that we will call `category`. I am rendering a variable of about ~300 counties for a `varinterest` for a `category`, but I would also like to fill the counties with missing data as gray.

My current method is as follows:

```
tm_shape(data) + 
     tm_fill() +
tm_shape(data %>% filter(category='cat1')) + 
     tm_polygons(varinterest) +
```

However, this is a bit slow (taking 5-7 minutes to render on a very strong computer). Mapping only the variable of interest (i.e. the second `tm_shape(...` takes only a few seconds.

I feel like I am missing something obvious that might speed up rendering - any advice?

I will work on a reproducible example and post my times.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a reproducible example.  Get county shapes from `USAboundaries`:

```
> library(USAboundaries)
> data = us_counties()
> dim(data)
[1] 3220   13
```

add a `category` column with about 300 in each category, and a `varinterest`

```
> data$category=paste0("cat",sample(1:10,nrow(data),TRUE))
> table(data$category)

 cat1 cat10  cat2  cat3  cat4  cat5  cat6  cat7  cat8  cat9 
  342   324   329   310   344   310   332   289   321   319 
> data$varinterest = runif(nrow(data))
```

Your `tm_shape` line looks a bit broken - you've got `category='cat1'` which needs a `==`, no quotes round `varinterest` which are necessary, and a stray `+` sign on the end. Fixing those gives:

```
> tm_shape(data) + tm_fill() + tm_shape(data %>% filter(category=='cat1')) + tm_fill("varinterest")
```

which runs in seconds on my mediocre computer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reproducible example, @Spacedman! Apologeis for the mistakes, I typed it up quick without my reference code. Beyond the small issues, do you think tm_fill() would speed up the rendering process? I am currently doing a tm_polygons() for my `varinterest`, and a tm_fill for the gray background.

Comment: Does my code do what you want, and does it still take 5-7 minutes for you with your data on your computer? There's no timing difference between `tm_fill` and `tm_polygons`. Is my reproducible example still slow for you?

Comment: Hmm...both are taking the same amount of time on my computer and getting your results (<10 seconds for both both tm_fill("varinterest") and tm_polygons("varinterest")). I'm guessing that this must be a dataframe problem - the dataframes from which I am subsetting the data are quite large, so perhaps I need to create some additional objects that are simplified...

For example, one of the data objects is ~26000 rows with 100 variables. I use that same object to render the gray background, the fill variable, and the state outline.

Comment: You said you were using a ~3000 row counties data and a ~300 row subset. Where does the 26,000x100 dataset come into it? Want to delete this question and start again with a reproducible example?

Comment: Sorry - it is still US counties but it is longitudinal with many variables. I can delete to avoid confusion and it seems reducing the size of dataframes has improved speed (albeit only slightly).